# how to remove the strings(\test me) from an array in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have  variable like this below strings
$a="\test1 me \test2 \test3 \test4 \test5"

how to remove the **\test1 me** and **\test4** from $a?

I want final output like below!!!!
$a="\test2 \test3 \test5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the test vars to remove are always constant you can use the replace switch

```
-replace "var2remove","replacewith"
```

If your vars are always in the same location and not constant text you can also parse the array as long as it is delimited somehow- do this by calling the only the objects in the array you need. If you have 4 objects in the array but only need the the first:

```
$var[1]
```

This will return the fest over in the delimited array. Both of these methods for string /array manipulation can be cumbersome with automation and larger scripts, usually if I have an issue with powershell arrays I try to swim upstream in the data and make changes there. Powershell is an amazing tool but it is not very agile when parsing feeds that where not originated in native .net/wmi- not compared to Py or R. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it works. my values are always constant. i have only one problem here: the slash is not replacing it throws an error message     -replace "\test1 me","replacewith"

Comment: Try escaping the \ with another \. So the code would look like this:

Comment: -replace "\\test1 me","replacewith"

Comment: thank you very much. I am new to powershell, this helps lot!!

Comment: I am assuming that the escape worked and solved your error?

Comment: yes. Can you help me how to split with semicolan if I have string like this $a="\test1 me \test2\test2 sub folder \test3 \test4\test4 folder\test4 subfolder \test5". Basically I want output like this---- \test1 me, \test2\test2 sub folder ,\test3,\test4\test4 folder\test4 subfolder,\test5